# HTML jQuery submit returns Latitude and Longitude

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have an HTML form that I want to be able to fill out, then submit, then have latitude and longitude appear on submit. It seems to be working but lat and long only appear for a split second.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <h2>Test Form</h2>
    <form id="address" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText1">Street</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street_name" placeholder="Street" ng-model="street" name="street_address">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText2">House Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street_number" placeholder="House Number" ng-model="housenumber" name="house_number">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText3">Postal Code</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="postal_code" placeholder="Postal Code" ng-model="postalcode" name="postal_code">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputText4">City</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" ng-model="city" name="city">
        </div>
       <button id="sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">SAVE</button>
        <label for="id_lat">Latitude</label><input type="text" name="lat" value="0.000000" id="id_lat" />
        <label for="id_lng">Longitude</label><input type="text" name="lng" value="0.000000" id="id_lng" />
    </form>
</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var geocoder;
        var address;
        $('#address').submit(function() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            address = $('#street_name').val() + " " + $('street_number').val() + " " + $('#postal_code').val() + ", " + $('#city').val();
            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#id_lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat().toFixed(6));
                $('#id_lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng().toFixed(6));
                $('#address').unbind('submit');
                $('#address').submit();
              } else {
                $('#address').unbind('submit');
                $('#address').submit();
              }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They only appear briefly because you are doing:

```
$('#address').unbind('submit');
$('#address').submit();
```

This will cause the form to submit by browser default process and page will reload.

It's not clear what your intentions are for doing this

Comment: How do I keep the page from reloading?

Comment: Remove those lines. As mentioned I don't know why they were there or what your intentions were

Comment: That worked. New to jQuery. Obviously need more practice. Thanks for the help friend!

Answer (score 0):

The value of the field is resetting from the HTML because of `$('#address').submit();`.

If you change the value with jQuery after this it will work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#address').submit(function() {
         $('#id_lat').val("5");
         $('#id_lng').val("5");
         $('#address').submit();
         });
       $('#id_lng').val("5");
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pjpwea/y4L9qc58/

Comment out the second `$('#id_lng').val("5");` in the example to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is getting executed but the page is also getting refreshed which is why you see the result for a split second.

If you submit a form it will redirect to the url of the action parameter. When there is no action parameter the page will refresh.

You can prevent the page from refreshing by preventing the form to be actually send.

Replace this line `$('#address').submit(function() {`
With the lines below:

```
$('#address').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: `return false` as OP is using will prevent default also. Form is refreshing page for a different reason

Comment: I've tried it in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tw5avcj4/4/  When you uncomment the preventDefault line you will see the difference. I've seen more ocassions where return false wasn't properly preventing the form from being submit.

Comment: But you didn't check errors in console because `google` and `geocoder` are undefined and it just throws errors which blocks the return